# Let $Y\sim~\text{Exp}(\lambda)$. What is $P(|Y-\frac1\lambda|>a)$ with $a>\frac1\lambda$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I think, that I need to find the density of $|Y-\frac1\lambda|$. I also know, that for independent random variables $X,Y$, the density of $X+Y$ is $\int f(y)\cdot g(x-y)\,dy$. However I am having troubles with actually applying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\begin{align}P\left(\left|Y-\frac1\lambda\right|>a\right) &= P\left(Y-\frac1\lambda>a\right) + P\left(Y-\frac1\lambda<-a\right)\\&=P\left(Y>a+\frac1\lambda\right) + P\left(Y<\frac1\lambda-a\right) \end{align}$$